# Reading in CDATA XML to SQL Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, openxml

I have a perplexing issue with a "[CDATA]" XML document. I'm trying to create a tabular format for it in SQL Server.  Below is a snippet of what the XML looks like:

```
    ''''
    <root>
    <response success="true">
        <output>
            <![CDATA[Account Name,Account Code,Level Name,"Employee",01/2021,02/2021,03/2021
    "Hours Used","Predicted.HoursUsed","Non-Labor","A, Apple A",261.0,232.0,240.0
    "Hours Used","Predicted.HoursUsed","Non-Labor","B, Orange L",0.0,72.0,368.0
    "Hours Used","Predicted.HoursUsed","Non-Labor","C'Pear, D",0.0,0.0,0.0
    "Hours Used","Predicted.HoursUsed","Non-Labor","D, Grape
    A",302.0,300.5,358.5]]>
        </output>
    </response>
    </root>

    ''''
```

I would like to transform the above to a table like below:

| Account Name | Account Code | Level Name | Employee | 01/2021 | 02/2021 | 03/2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Hours Used | Predicted.HoursUsed | Non-Labor | A, Apple A | 261.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 |
| Hours Used | Predicted.HoursUsed | Non-Labor | B, Orange L | 232.0 | 72.0 | 0.0 |
| Hours Used | Predicted.HoursUsed | Non-Labor | C'Pear, D | 240.0 | 368.0 | 0.0 |

I tried variations using "OPENXML" but it hasn't been working to parse out the data.  I'm not sure what else I'm missing.  Appreciate the help!

Thank you.

Comment: _"I tried variations using "OPENXML""_ -- show what you tried. _"it hasn't been working"_ -- explain what didn't work.

Comment: Hi Jim, I tried to use "OPENXML(@xml,  'ROOT/response/output')" and it says xml is incompatible with int.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include ALL the information requested -- i.e. the code.

Comment: Well the CDATA element is not XML, it's just a blob of text in some unspecified CSV format. You're not going to have an easy time parsing that

Comment: Unless you feel like writing a state machine-driven CSV parser in pure SQL you're going to have to handle this externally with PowerShell, C#, etc.. You're starting with CSV data that has embedded line breaks (e.g.: Grape-linefeed-A), and the CDATA encoding "breaks" the format by inserting whitespace at the beginning of each line. SQL Server is a relational database, it's not well suited to string handling hijinx.

Answer (score 0):

This solution kinda works, except the indexes are static.  And for some reason the replace doesn't seem to be working to remove the commas in names.

''''

```
DECLARE @doc XML
   = '<root>
    <response success="true">
        <output>
            <![CDATA[Account Name,Account Code,Level 
Name,"Employee",01/2021,02/2021,03/2021, 04/2021
    "Hours Used","EAC_Hours.HoursUsed","Unaligned Non-Labor","A, Apple 
A",261.0,232.0,240.0,55.0
    "Hours Used","EAC_Hours.HoursUsed","Unaligned Non-Labor","B, Orange 
L",0.0,72.0,368.0,165.0
    "Hours Used","EAC_Hours.HoursUsed","Unaligned Non-Labor","C''Pear, 
D",0.0,0.0,0.0,0.8
    "Hours Used","EAC_Hours.HoursUsed","Unaligned Non-Labor","D, Grape    
A",302.0,300.5,358.5,188.0]]>
        </output>
    </response>
    </root>';

DECLARE @hnd INT;
DECLARE @string NVARCHAR(1000);


EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hnd OUTPUT, @doc;

SELECT *
FROM OPENXML

(@hnd, '/root', 0);

SELECT @string = text
FROM OPENXML(@hnd, '/root', 0)
WHERE nodetype = 3
      AND localname = '#text'
      AND parentid = 4;

--SELECT REPLACE(@string,'"Hours Used"','zzz')
SET @string = REPLACE(@string, '   "', '|"');
SELECT value
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@string, '|');


((Select Cast('<x>' + replace(value,',','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) AS 
Record
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@string, '|'))
         
EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hnd;
```

''''